# POD multilanguage documentation

Tags: perl, perl-pod

Is there any way to write multilanguage documentation using POD? If no, what should I write it in (I already have POD documentation in English, so I will want to convert it and then translate)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you're asking whether POD supports non-English encoding, the answer is a resounding YES. Here's an example of brian d foy's article (in POD format) translated into Russian: http://perlrussia.ru/article/brians-guide/brian%27s_guide.ru.pod
2. If you are wondering if it's possible to stick multi-language POD into the same file, there's a fairly curious example here:
   http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/HIO/Unicode-Japanese-0.47/lib/Unicode/Japanese.mlpod

   **It uses [Pod::Multilang](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Pod-MultiLang/)**

   However, i'm not entirely certain how (or even if) it works, as I could not find two examples of html generated straight from that mlpod.
3. See http://perldoc2.sourceforge.net/ - this is a project for international perldoc

Answer (score 2):

If you're preparing your module for distribution on CPAN, create separate `.pod` files for the translations of your documentation.

For example, if you have included the English documentation in `My/Module.pm`, you could create the files `My/Module-jp.pod`, `My/Module-ru.pod`, etc.:

```
=head1 NAME

My::Module-pl - Atin-lay Ig-pay ocumentation-day or-fay y-may odule-may

=head1 ERSION-VAY

1.01

=head1 ESCRIPTION-DAY

...
```

Comment: That is how I do now. Is it the official way?

Comment: @ZyX - I'm not sure there's an "official" way but it seems a popular way for at least russian modules which I saw when researching my answer to this question.